# get full html after element's properties changed

Tags: html

ex I've a page:

```
<body><input type='checkbox' /></body>
```

after I set checked on checkbox, I get result html of body tag:

```
<body><input type='checkbox' /></body>
```

why? I want result after I get html:

```
<body><input type='checkbox' checked /></body>
```

Comment: How do you get the html ? Do you use jQuery .html() ?

Comment: anything without add event for checkboxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checked` **attribute** describes the **default** checked state of the control.

Setting the `checked` **property** or clicking on the checkbox will set the **current** value.

If you want to change the attribute, then you must do so explicitly with JavaScript.

e.g.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', setAttribute);

function setAttribute(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    this.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
    this.removeAttribute('checked');
  }
  alert(this.parentNode.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="1">
  Input
</label>
```

Comment: thank you, your code's cool but I feel it's not absolute because I don't want add EventListener.